# Mongo Query is too slow

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection with over 1.2TB of data.
I have a index on the userId and not on creation date, when i query data by just the userId the query is fast but when i add creation date with userId its visibly slow i.e. 4-5 sec

when i query

```
db.collection.find({"userId" : "12345"}).count()
```

this returns count 1300 instantaneously

same is the case for

```
db.collection.find({"userId" : "12345"}).limit(1)
```

but when i query with creation time

```
db.collection.find({"userId" : "12345"}).sort({"createdAt" : 1}).limit(1)
```

it takes close to 4-5 sec

avg size of document is 1.5KB

given that the amount of data for the index is low i.e. 1300 it should have take less than 1 sec correct, even if it has to bring all the 1300 documents and sort it should not have taken that long, am i wrong in assuming so? what am i missing?

I am happy  to provide any other info needed

Comment: Slave is just a backup and as such all queries read and write go to master.
when i ran the same query is slave(secondary) it was 10 times faster

Comment: Maybe you could add `createdAt` to your index: `{ userId: 1, createdAt: 1}`. This will avoid the sorted in memory and should be faster.

Comment: that i agree adding composite will definitely help but i want to understand why this is taking soo long as u can see, the amount of data is 1300 for this specific id which i assume should be low

Comment: You could examine the output of [`explain`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/ "Link to MongoDB reference manual -->").